# The name does not exist in the current context, ApiController, asp.net core, IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm making a service that return a list IEnumerable, the trouble is that when return the element IEnumerable appear this error: *The name 'ActivitiesList' does not exist in the current context*
I share you my code, the error appear in the last line: *return ActivitiesList;*

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("user/get-user-activities")]
        public IEnumerable<ActivitiesClass> GetUserActivities()
        {
            string email = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
            try
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
                {
                    using (SecondAppContext db = new SecondAppContext())
                    {
                        using (var transaccion = new TransactionScope())
                        {
                            User UserModel = db.User
                                       .Where(b => b.Email == email)
                                       .First();
                            var IdUser = UserModel.Id;
                            IEnumerable<ActivitiesClass> ActivitiesList = 
                            (
                                from activity in db.Activities
                                where activity.IdUser == IdUser &&
                                activity.DateCreated > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3)
                                select new ActivitiesClass 
                                {
                                    dataCreated = activity.DateCreated,
                                    description = activity.Description,
                                    category = activity.Category,
                                    gender = activity.Gender,
                                    ageMin = (int)activity.AgeMin,
                                    ageMax = (int)activity.AgeMax
                                }).ToList();
                            transaccion.Complete();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Error(ex.ToString());
            }
            return ActivitiesList;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the name 'ActivitiesList' does not exist in the current context

The issue relates that you are defining the `ActivitiesList` in the `if` statement, so it will show the above error. Besides, since the `IEnumerable<T>` is an interface, I suggest you could define a `List<ActivitiesClass>` instance to store the return data.

Try to modify your code as below:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("user/get-user-activities")]
    public IEnumerable<ActivitiesClass> GetUserActivities()
    {
        string email = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);

        //define a List<ActivitiesClass> to store the return data.
        List<ActivitiesClass> ActivitiesList = new List<ActivitiesClass>();

        try
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
            {
                using (SecondAppContext db = new SecondAppContext())
                {
                    using (var transaccion = new TransactionScope())
                    {
                        User UserModel = db.User
                                   .Where(b => b.Email == email)
                                   .First();
                        var IdUser = UserModel.Id;

                        //set values for the ActivitiesList 
                        ActivitiesList =
                        (
                            from activity in db.Activities
                            where activity.IdUser == IdUser &&
                            activity.DateCreated > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3)
                            select new ActivitiesClass
                            {
                                dataCreated = activity.DateCreated,
                                description = activity.Description,
                                category = activity.Category,
                                gender = activity.Gender,
                                ageMin = (int)activity.AgeMin,
                                ageMax = (int)activity.AgeMax
                            }).ToList();
                        transaccion.Complete();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Error(ex.ToString());
        }
        return ActivitiesList; //Call the `.AsEnumerable()` method, if you want to convert the List to the IEnumerable<>.
    }
```

After calling this method, if the IEnumerable result doesn't contain records, it means not matched data.

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to be mindful of scopes..
2. Yuo need to be thinking about returning an error code if something isn't as expect
3. You should be using the *async and await pattern*.
4. There is no need for a transaction here
5. Also you should use standard casing and naming conventions  e.g `User userModel`

**Untested Example**

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<ActivitiesClass>> GetUserActivities()
{
   string email = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);

   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
      return null; // you should think about this

   try
   {
      await using var db = new SecondAppContext();

      // what are yu going to if the user is not found?
      var userModel = await db.User
         .Where(b => b.Email == email)
         .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

      if (userModel == null)
         return null; // you should think about this

      return await (
         from activity in db.Activities
         where activity.IdUser == userModel.Id && activity.DateCreated > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3)
         select new ActivitiesClass
         {
            dataCreated = activity.DateCreated,
            description = activity.Description,
            category = activity.Category,
            gender = activity.Gender,
            ageMin = (int) activity.AgeMin,
            ageMax = (int) activity.AgeMax
         }).ToListAsync();

   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      Error(ex.ToString());
   }

   return null; // you should think about this
}
```

Comment: Thank you, please say me why I don't need use the transaction?